# Confused About null safety

Tags: flutter

I have created a class, and I am getting this error
the operand can’t be null, so the condition is always false.
I am new to flutter and null safety. How can I fix this

```dart
    class DatabaseHelper{

    static late  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
    factory DatabaseHelper{
    if(_databaseHelper==null){
      _databaseHelper=DatabaseHelper.internal();
      return _databaseHelper;
    }else{
      return _databaseHelper;

    }
    }
    DatabaseHelper.internal();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared using `late`  `static late  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;`

Means it will never get `null` value before read time. And it's just a warning can be ignored.

But if you wish to check value is `null` or not, or can be null at time, make nullable
like   `static   DatabaseHelper? _databaseHelper;`

And when you return it you need to use bang operator `!` in some cases,
like  `return _databaseHelper!;`

More details

- [null-safety faq](https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq)
- [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety)